# Remember last user entry of a form component within a session

Tags: forms, session, wicket

I am working on a small web application in Wicket with the following requirement:

If a user enters several values into a small form, sends this form and returns to this very same form later on, the form is already filled with the user's previous entries. Would I store all these values in the user session object? Or is there a better best practice? I feel like I am polluting the session object with cashed data.

PS: Loosing the values after a longer while is not the issue. The values should be remembered while the user is browsing since it is possible that the user will confirm a similar search request several times.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) if this is an option for you. Then you dont need wicket for this, you do this in JavaScript.

In your Panel or whereever you override renderHead and render there some java script which populates your form components with the values from sessionStorage if they are present.